# Spring Boot Warn, when launching service - "Bean'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration'"

Tags: java, spring-boot, warnings, spring-bean

After migrating Spring Boot version from 2.7.14 to 3.2.2 I get a warning when I start the service.

WARN [info-service,,]" 50964 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [lbRestClientPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

OR

" WARN [info-service,,]" 50964 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'default.org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.config.LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration.LoadBalancerClientSpecification' of type [org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.annotation.LoadBalancerClientSpecification] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [lbRestClientPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

Before migrate version everything worked properly. I tried to find documentation or way to solve this issue but could not.

Comment: Have you ever read this ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide